# Expressing variables in echo with mysqli

Tags: variables, mysqli, echo

Attempting to switch to mysqli but I can't seem to show the variables within the echo.

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<div class="content">$row["name"]</div>';
}
```

Within the echo there is html and I would like to show the value within this but can't find the correct way to do it

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please post valid questions with complete code.

Comment: Your code snippet appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<div class="content">'.$row["name"].'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if $id is not `empty()` and `is_numeric()`

and if it's OK check your query syntax

also i suggest that you turn on error_reporting so you know what's the error that causing this :))